# Automating 'To' from Contacts List Gmail

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, gmail

When you compose an e-mail in Gmail, to send the email to people on your Contacts list you have to click 'To' which leads you to a pop-up box. Is there a way to automate the closing of this box? I'm using Selenium and C#.

Comment: Since when? I always just start typing a name and let autocomplete pull from the list.

Comment: I'm trying to automate it. I currently have no contacts, so I want to press either the close button(upper-right) or the cancel button(bottom of the page), but I find no way to automate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're likely running into problems because that modular window is within an iFrame, and you need to tell Selenium to specifically look into that iFrame before searching.

See [handling-iframes-using-selenium-webdriver](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/handling-iframes-using-selenium-webdriver/).

Unfortunately, Google seems to assign a new ID to this iframe every time it's created, so you can't rely on that, so you'll need to create an IWebElement for the iframe element and pass it into the .SwithTo().Frame() call.

Specifically, you could try this (I tested this out, and it worked for me).

```
//Get iFrame element and switch to it.
IWebElement selectContactFrame= driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("iframe.KA-JQ"));
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(selectContactFrame);

//Find cancel button and click it.
IWebElement cancelButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[text()='Cancel']"));
cancelButton.Click();
```